# How do I pick the right type of grass for my lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass

I'm trying to pick a type of grass for my backyard lawn. I've researched some on Wikipedia such as:

Kikuyu grass:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pennisetum_clandestinum

Kentucky Bluegrass:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poa_pratensis

Bermuda Grass:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bermuda_grass

But still don't know which is best for an Arizona (USA) backyard. I've had the guy from the nursery come out and look but he's never heard of Kikuyu grass so is not much help.

Anyone out there have experience with multiple grass types in Phoenix, AZ?

Comment: Have you had a soil analysis done? How much do you want to have to water? I'd check with your local extension office to make sure something like kikuyu is not considered invasive in your area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look into [Buffalo Grass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouteloua_dactyloides). It sounds perfect for Arizona.

- It's drought resistant, so you won't have to water it too much.
- It's heat resistant, so it won't melt in your hot, hot summers.
- It's cold resistant, so it won't freeze on your frosty mornings.

Also it's pretty hard to kill. Here are some [Buffalo](http://ucverdeblog.com/2009/04/20/follow-this-phoenix-arizona-gardener-as-she-installs-her-uc-verde-buffalo-grass/) [Grass](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/lawns/msg0310371213116.html) blogs from Phoenix